# What does 'shyme' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, orthography, is-it-a-word, non-standard

Reading [*Dracula*](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/345/pg345-images.html), I found this sentence:

> It’s a **shyme** that people are allowed to top their walls with broken bottles

In no dictionary was I able to find a definition; ChatGPT says that it is a misspelling of *shame*, but the book is old/well-known enough that I think they would have enough time to fix this mistake. So, what is it, precisely?

Comment: It's an attempted phonetic rendition of the dialect pronunciation of _shame_, intended.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - it's a bladdy shyme, guvnor!

Comment: We Brits call that dialect 'Dick van Dyke'.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looking at it in context, it appears the author is *deliberately* misspelling words to capture features of the character Thomas Bilder's accent. The wonderful paper ["Nonstandard Language and the Cultural Stakes of Stoker's 'Dracula'" by Ferguson (2004)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30029928) describes him as a "cockney" (p. 241). As [the table on Wikipedia shows,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) in Cockney the vowel in *shame* would be pronounced [æɪ~aɪ], much like how speakers of some other dialects would pronounce the vowel in *shy,* so spelling *shame* as "shyme" would be a sensible way of capturing that feature of the dialect in question.

Comment: Related to this answer, you'll find this from a number of other authors too.  Charles Dickens often used this to give the phonetic "feel" of someone's accent.  His phonetic spelling was good enough that it's been used to track changes in accent over time. George Orwell commented in *Down and out in Paris and London* (written in the 1930s) that some aspects of the Cockney dialect such as pronouncing "v" as "w" had been lost in the years since Dickens.

Comment: It's not only done with Cockney accents; many accents/dialects where the pronunciation has a significant divergence from "standard" English (either UK Standard Received or US "Midwest Newscaster") will be represented by false-phonetic spelling where representing the accent/dialect is considered important for showing the character of the... er, character.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the word for this is “eye dialect.”

Answer (score 10):

This is the word "shame". It's spelled as "shyme" to represent how it sounds in the local accent. It's apparently Cockney, or something similar; if you're unfamiliar with this accent, watch the movie "My Fair Lady" and notice the accent of Eliza and her friends/family. A hallmark of this accent is that in many words, a long "a" is pronounced like "aye".

Comment: My mother was as Cockney as they come, and so were all of her brothers and sisters (except one who went to live in Orpington) and they didn't say 'shame' like that.

Comment: It's the stereotype. But maybe it's an exaggeration for Americans -- how does Audrey Hepburn's accent in My Fair Lady compare to your family's?

Comment: Hepburn's 'Cockney' accent sounds nothing like my mother's family's accent. It sounds like what it is - an actorly exaggeration for Americans. In fact it's not even exaggeration of her own accent - it's self-taught imitation. She was born in Belgium to aristocratic English parents, was privately educated there and in Kent, and spent a lot of her youth in the Netherlands.

Comment: I have seen praise by critics of Hepburn's 'accent'; it wouldn't fool any British person.

Comment: In fact only her father was [technically] British; her mother was a Dutch aristocrat, and her father was of British/Austrian heritage.

Comment: Brits seem to do better at imitating American accents (or maybe dialect coaching has gotten better since the 60's). There are lots of them on American TV (e.g. both Andrew Lincoln and Lauren Cohan on The Walking Dead) and it's impossible to tell.

Comment: For another point of comparison, how about Dick Van Dyke in Mary Poppins? I don't think it's as extreme as Hepburn.

Comment: For Brits, the Dick Van Dyke 'accent' is a well known joke. It is comically and ridiculously wrong. I thought you might have already know that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Unfortunately, most of my exposure to British accents outside shows made for American audiences is from Monty Python. So it's hard to know what's authentic.

Comment: Your rule of thumb might be that apart from Gillian Anderson (who grew up in Surrey), Americans don't do Brit accents. Even Brits take the money to do silly ones for US audiences, like Jane Leeves as Daphne on Frasier. She is not from Manchester, and her accent is hilariously false.

Comment: Just lately, we've had Sarah Lancashire 'doing' Julia Child. I wonder how convincing she is to New Englanders?

Comment: 'Brits seem to do better at imitating American accents'  -well, we have been exposed to the output of the US entertainment industry for around 100 years now, whereas the converse is not true to  the same extent, so maybe we've had more practice? I can do an amazing Deputy Dawg (plus Muskie into the bargain), and have been able to since I was 12.

Comment: Not to mention that Hollywood is effectively the world's entertainment HQ, so lots more Brits come here than the other way around. So there's more call for learning our accents.